# Markov chain average waiting time

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given the following $E=\{1,2,3\}$ and matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/6\\ 
1/4 & 3/4 & 0\\ 
 1/2& 0 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$, assuming that chain starts from point 1 find average time required to reach state two. I know i have to set up a  system of equations: $$
t_2=0,  t_1=1/2t_1+1/3t_2+1/6 t_3+1,
 t_3=1/2t_3+1/2t_1+1 
$$ where t stands for time. However the only thing i do not understand is this 1 we are adding. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the equations is conditioning on the first step. In words, the mean time to hit state 2 starting from state 1 is the sum of the mean time to hit state 2 starting from state i, times the probability to go directly to state i from state 1, plus one, to account for the first step itself.

In symbols you might write something like:

$$E[\tau \mid X_0=1]=\sum_i E[\tau \mid X_0=1,X_1=i]P[X_1=i \mid X_0=1] \\=\sum_i (E[\tau \mid X_0=i]+1)P[X_1=i \mid X_0=1]$$

where we have used the Markov property to simplify the conditional expectations in the sum.

Comment: But why we have to account for the first step separately? Do not get it.

Comment: @mkropkowski The first step takes a time unit. When you recurse to compute the expected time after the first step, you are only keeping track of the time taken after the first step. So if you don't add in the $+1$, you will wind up finding that the expected value is just zero.